# MATLAB: Removing 4 lines of header repeated every 14 lines & keeping 2nd/3rd columns of data in txt file

Tags: matlab, header

Basically I have a bunch of repeated data in a bunch of text files that looks like the following (showing two sections):

```
t0  1/20/2012  05:41:05.068750
delta t 0.100000

time    Y
1/20/2012  05:41:05.068750  0.925883
1/20/2012  05:41:05.168750  0.926540
1/20/2012  05:41:05.268750  0.926540
1/20/2012  05:41:05.368750  0.926540
1/20/2012  05:41:05.468750  0.926869
1/20/2012  05:41:05.568750  0.925225
1/20/2012  05:41:05.668750  0.926540
1/20/2012  05:41:05.768750  0.928185
1/20/2012  05:41:05.868750  0.925554
1/20/2012  05:41:05.968750  0.925225
t0  1/20/2012  05:41:06.068750
delta t 0.100000

time    Y
1/20/2012  05:41:06.068750  0.926212
1/20/2012  05:41:06.168750  0.924567
1/20/2012  05:41:06.268750  0.926540
1/20/2012  05:41:06.368750  0.925883
1/20/2012  05:41:06.468750  0.914371
1/20/2012  05:41:06.568750  0.907135
1/20/2012  05:41:06.668750  0.906806
1/20/2012  05:41:06.768750  0.903188
1/20/2012  05:41:06.868750  0.902201
1/20/2012  05:41:06.968750  0.906148
```

I need a way in MATLAB to keep only the 10 rows of data in the second and third columns (time without date and y value) and store it all in a variable so that I can write it out to a new text or xls file. I don't even really need the time value since every y value is taken in 0.1 second increments. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch process:

```matlab
% Slurp in all lines.
f = fopen('foo.txt');
c = textscan(f,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
lines = c{1};
fclose(f);

% Remove headers.
lines(1:14:end) = [];
lines(1:13:end) = [];
lines(1:12:end) = [];
lines(1:11:end) = [];

% Extract data.
output = zeros(numel(lines),2);
for i = 1:numel(lines)
    x = lines{i};
    output(i,1) = datenum(x(1:19),'mm/dd/yyyy  HH:MM:SS') + ...
        str2double(x(20:26));
    output(i,2) = str2double(x(28:end));
end
```

Or as a state machine:

```matlab
f = fopen('foo.txt');
output = [];
while true
    for i = 1:4
        x = fgetl(f);
        if x == -1
            break
        end
    end
    for i = 1:10
        x = fgetl(f);
        if x == -1
            break
        end
        time = datenum(x(1:19),'mm/dd/yyyy  HH:MM:SS') + ...
            str2double(x(20:26));
        val = str2double(x(28:end));
        output(end+1,1:2) = [time,val];
    end
    if x == -1
        break
    end
end
fclose(f);
```